# ServeStatic not defined - pure node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

It is my first day coding nodejs. This is a code example from a book called node.js in action. It's a nice book with some great information about how to code node.js as a beginner. but already after 1 day, i run into an error. I have copied the code and tried everything but nothing seems to work. This is the code I can't get to work.

My error when trying to run: ReferenceError: serveStatic is not defined

---

I have now installed the module and required it in my file.
Now i get a new error: "TypeError: root path must be a string"

---

Now it says

TypeError: root path must be a string
    at serveStatic (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learningmern/chatapp1/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:44

```
   var http     =   require("http");
    var fs      =   require("fs");
    var path    =   require("path");
    var mime    =   require("mime");

    var cache = {}



// Helper functions
function send404(res){
    res.writeHead(404,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    res.write("error 4o4");
    res.end();
}

function sendFile(res, filePath, fileContents){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": mime.lookup(path.basename(filePath)) });
    res.end(fileContents);
}

function serveCache(res, cache, absPath){
    if (cache[absPath]){
        readFile(res, absPath, cache[absPath]);
    } else {
        fs.exists(absPath, function(exists){
            if (exists){
                fs.readFile(absPath, function(err, data){
                    if (err){
                        send404(res);
                    } else {
                        cache[absPath] = data;
                        fs.readFile(res, absPath, data);
                    }
                })
            } else {
                send404(res);
            }
        })
    }
}


//run server
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    var filePath = false;

    if (req.url == "/"){
        filePath = "public/index.html";
    } else {
        filePath = "public" + req.url;
    }

    var absPath = "./" + filePath;
    serveStatic(res, cache, absPath);
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server started at port 3000");
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package. Run this:

```
npm install serve-static
```

Also require it. Put this at the top require section.

```
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Now it says "TypeError: root path must be a string"

Comment: TypeError: root path must be a string
    at serveStatic (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learningmern/chatapp1/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:44

Comment: Your book is likely showing how to use an older version of serveStatic. Please check out the usage here: https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static for the current version. It should only take two parameters, your example shows 3. Utilize console.log debug what various variables are and keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed `server-static` npm, here is the solution to the error you are dealing with. You are calling the variables before you define them so you'd change your code to

```
   var http     =   require("http");
    var fs      =   require("fs");
    var path    =   require("path");
    var mime    =   require("mime");
    var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

    var filePath = ""; //define filePath here for the functions to not run an error
    var absPath = "./" + filePath;
    var cache = {};
    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){


    if (req.url == "/"){
        filePath = "public/index.html";
    } else {
        filePath = "public" + req.url;
    }


    serveStatic(res, cache, absPath);
   });



// Helper functions
function send404(res){
    res.writeHead(404,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
    res.write("error 4o4");
    res.end();
}

function sendFile(res, filePath, fileContents){
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": mime.lookup(path.basename(filePath)) });
    res.end(fileContents);
}

function serveCache(res, cache, absPath){
    if (cache[absPath]){
        readFile(res, absPath, cache[absPath]);
    } else {
        fs.exists(absPath, function(exists){
            if (exists){
                fs.readFile(absPath, function(err, data){
                    if (err){
                        send404(res);
                    } else {
                        cache[absPath] = data;
                        fs.readFile(res, absPath, data);
                    }
                })
            } else {
                send404(res);
            }
        })
    }
}


//run server

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server started at port 3000");
});
```

Comment: it now says : "TypeError: root path must be a string
    at serveStatic "

Comment: change `res` object to `"/"` also check out this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static

Comment: TypeError: root path must be a string
    at serveStatic (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/learningmern/chatapp1/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:44